# Is a sim-free iPhone different from a virtual-sim iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sim, cellular-carriers

We read that Apple has a [patent](http://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2014/11/patent-fulfilled-the-new-apple-sim-patent-comes-to-light.html) on a 'virtual sim' iPhone.

Then we saw that Apple was [selling](https://9to5mac.com/2016/10/13/sim-free-iphone-7-and-iphone-7-plus/) a 'sim-free' iPhone.

Both allow you to choose your carrier later. These appear to be different concepts.

My question is: **Is a sim-free iphone different to a virtual-sim iphone?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No no, Apple is selling the phone only, without a SIM or a carrier plan.  That's what SIM free means. The device ships without a SIM. You need to buy a SIM card separately . But a virtual SIM is a completely different thing.
A virtual SIM is a concept in which no SIM card is needed and the protected storage is inside the phone. So you can switch carriers without changing a SIM